# JBehave does not fail build when exception occurs

Tags: java, maven, build, jbehave

I am using JBehave to run tests written using WebDriver. Maven is used to automate build process. And now when I run tests and they fail ie throwing exceptions about timeouts etc the whole build does not break.

Here is sample output with exception:

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zvuD2nDX)

Can anyone tell me why build does not fail after that and how to make it fail? If you need more info please let me know what.

Answer (score 0):

When setting up your [`org.jbehave.core.configuration.Configuration`](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/javadoc/core/org/jbehave/core/configuration/Configuration.html) object, add:

```
myConfiguration.usePendingStepStrategy(new FailingUponPendingStep())
```

Comment: Shouldn't this annotation be enough: 
    @Configure(storyReporterBuilder = MyReportBuilder.class, pendingStepStrategy = FailingUponPendingStep.class)
?

Answer (score 0):

In my project I use maven-failsafe-plugin to execute tests and I encountered the same problem. The solution is to add a verify phase to failsafe:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>failsafe-verify</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

While 5 years late, and not actually an answer to the question asked in 2012, jBehave 4.0 has a bug where Maven runs [do not trigger a failure from Maven when using jBehave 4.0+](https://jbehave.atlassian.net/browse/JBEHAVE-1099).

So if you've gotten here from Googling in 2017 or 2018, check out the ticket as it may contain answers to your problem (which, as of this writing in 2017, is "downgrade to 3.9.5...)

Answer (score 0):

May be setting the following property can help:
`-Dignore.failure.in.view=false`